# How to host Codeigniter app on Azure?

Tags: php, codeigniter, azure

I wanted to ask you to help me (with some tutorial link or something), what i want to do is to upload php Codeigniter application on azure?

Also in my application, I got upload feature so I should make it work too (don't know if it's more complex becasue of that).

I was using wamp during developing, now I need to push it on server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, deploy a CI application to Azure Web Apps is simple, you can simply create an Azure Web Apps on [Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com), then step in the manage page of your Azure Web Apps, click **All settings**=>**deployment source**=>**chose source**=>**Local Git Repository** to set the git deployment setting of your Azure Web Apps service.
[image]

Then you can find the **Git clone url** under the essential tab.
[image]

Additionally, Azure App Service can run php composer.phar install when you run git push, but it's not enabled by default. To enable it, you need to install the [Composer extension](http://www.siteextensions.net/packages/ComposerExtension/) for your web app.

Here is a CI template on Azure sample, you can refer to https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-web-php-get-started for any hits.

And here is a video https://youtu.be/bBb_Hi2Odqc, you can refer to. It manages on the [classic portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com), but still works today.

Comment: At the end, I've had some problems with Git, so i had to use classic FTP transfer with TotalCommader, I've just put my project root to 0:/site/wwwroot/*.* and it's ok now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Deploying `Codeigniter` is very easy, all you need to make sure is placing the project directory correctly.

1. Just upload the project folder to the hosting either by **SSH** or **FTP**.
2. Modify the **.htaccess** file accordingly.
3. Once all the above is set up, including uploading all the files to host, don't forget to update `config.php` `database.php` and `route.php` with new hosting parameters.
4. To make your upload feature work correctly you just need to give proper/required write access to the upload folder of the application.

And that's all you need to do while deploying Codeigniter application.

Comment: So this are only files i need to edit before i deploy? I would deploy using git hope it's ok.

Comment: Looks like I'm in trouble, i've set: $config['base_url'] = "myname.azurewebsites.net/"; in config.php but still having this error: Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php. Have you got any idea what am i doing wrong? Btw. sorry if im asking newbie questions, but i'm first time trying something like this.

Comment: It is asking you to set the `$system_path` variable, which is the name/path of the system folder. If you've changed it, You need to update it. Make sure to update `$application_folder` too.